# How does spring handle multiple property-files?

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties

In a library project (I'll refer to it as LIB) I want to configure some default properties.

Something like this:

```
@Configuration
@PropertyResource("classpath:library.yaml")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "com.lib")
public class RemotePropertiesConfig {
    private String someProperty;
    // getters and setters
}
```

If I use a property file called *application.yaml* and the (springboot) application using my library has a property file with the same name, it seems like the *application.yaml* from LIB is being overwritten. That's why I want it to have a different name in my LIB. I called it *library.yaml*. In the config class (above) I have therefore added a *@PropertyResource()* annotation. However, when I test this in a springboot application, the properties from LIB remain *null*.

Does Spring not process my @PropertyResource annotation and therefore not load *library.yaml*?

Or

Is the *library.yaml* loaded, but does it get overwritten anyway?

Or ?

I'm quite clueless, for it works perfectly if I have an *application.yaml* in LIB and an *application.yml* (notice the difference yml/yaml) in the springboot application using my LIB. This is obviously error-prone and therefore not how I would like to keep it.

Comment: `@PropertySource` is for property files **not** yaml files. If you want yaml files you need some additional stuff in there. Next the `@PropertySource` aren't valid or used for `@ConfigurationProperties`. so either way it wouldn't work. Instead tell Spring Boot (with `spring.config.additional-locations`) to load your file as well. Finally if they are defaults why put it in property files instead of coding it into the `RemotePropertiesConfig` directly and thus let people override it by properties in `application.yaml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be late here, but ran into similar issue. The interesting point is springboot doesn't handle the yml file same way as it does .properties. For @PropertySource to load the yml correctly you need to provide the factory class.

Also, you are right about not using the application.yml in the library project as it will conflict with the later application referencing this library project.

**Few good references,**

Spring reference - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.13.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-exposing-yaml-to-spring

For implementation reference - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-yaml-propertysource